# How to Access Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel on Visual studios 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-office, visual-studio-extensions

I got Visual Studios 2013 from Dreamspark and i need to access the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel namespace but it says it does not exist.

can someone help me find out how i add it. This would be the first time I am adding a library that is not already included with the VS installation.

I really appreciate your help

What i am ultimately trying to do is this

[Using LinEst () in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242713/using-linest-in-net)

Comment: Actually I found the what my problem was.... 

I really did not know i needed to "add reference" to my project.

I added it in from the main menu (project-> add reference)

Now I wonder why visual studio does not preload libraries like these?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` is an assembly in [Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712616.aspx). Check if you have installed them with Visual Studio.

You can [install the tools in three occasions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712596.aspx):

- When you install Visual Studio 2013.
- When you install Microsoft Office 2013 or Office 2010.
- When you install the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime redistributable.

Comment: Actually I found the what my problem was.... 

I really did not know i needed to "add reference" to my project.

I added it in from the main menu (project-> add reference)

Now I wonder why visual studio does not preload libraries like these?

Comment: If Visual Studio perloaded all the assemblies that are mostly used, that would be a very long list. Only reference what you need. Less is better for optimization.